# Generating another column for table based on values in existing table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, mariadb

Assuming following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `item`(
`item_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`item_serial_number` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`item_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`)
)
```

and following inserts:

```
INSERT INTO `item` (`item_id`, `item_serial_number`, `item_type`) VALUES
(1, '11232141', 'laptop'),
(2, '22343252', 'printer'),
(3, '34234244', 'printer'),
(4, '78678678', 'charger');
```

Which SQL commands should I look at/for if I want to add another column, namely `item_type_id` which will look up on every `item_type` varchar field value and generate values like this:

```
------------------------
|ID| SERIAL   | TYPE   |
------------------------
|1 | 11232141 | laptop |
|2 | 22343252 | printer|
|3 | 34234244 | printer|
|4 | 78678678 | charger|
------------------------

->
----------------------------------
|ID| SERIAL   | TYPE   | TYPE_ID |
----------------------------------
|1 | 11232141 | laptop |   1     |
|2 | 22343252 | printer|   2     |
|3 | 34234244 | printer|   2     |
|4 | 78678678 | charger|   3     |
----------------------------------
```

Comment: You are approaching this incorrectly. Instead, normalize the database. Create a `Type_Master` table and store `Type_Id, Type_Name` there. And in the `item` table, just store the `Type_Id`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I'm aware that the approach is not standard, but this is a specific use-case.

Comment: Select..from..join (to whatever your item_type tables is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this correctly, create a `types` table:

```
create table types (
    type_id int auto_increment primary key,
    type varchar(255)
);

insert into types (type)
    select distinct type
    from item;
```

Then, fix your current table:

```
alter table item add type_id int;

alter table item add constraint fk_types_type_id
    foreign key (type_id) references types (type_id);
```

Then set the value:

```
update item i join
       types t
       on i.type = t.type
    set i.type_id = t.type_id;
```

And finally drop the old column:

```
alter table item drop column type;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
SELECT item_id AS ID, 
item_serial_number AS Serial,
item_type AS Type,
CASE 
    WHEN item_type = 'laptop' THEN 1
    WHEN item_type = 'printer' THEN 2
    WHEN item_type = 'charger' THEN 3
END TYPE_ID
FROM `inventory_item_temp`
```

You can use a lookup table if the list is big. If I guess you have the lookup table as below-

```
Table Name: Type_id_lookup

item_type    type_id
laptop       1
printer      2
charger      3
Mobile       4  -- Sample other item_type
```

Then the query will be-

```
SELECT 
A.item_id AS ID, 
A.item_serial_number AS Serial,
A.item_type AS Type,
B.type_id TYPE_ID
FROM `inventory_item_temp` A
LEFT JOIN `Type_id_lookup` B ON A.item_type = B.item_type
```

Comment: That is something that would work if I only had 3 types. Number of types is much greater, therefore use of ```CASE``` isn't best i think.

Comment: If that list is big, you can introduce a Lookup table with all Distinct Item_type with preassigned number value. Then just Join your table with Lookup and pick type_id from lookup table.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `DENSE_RANK` analytical function:

```
select ID, SERIAL, TYPE, 
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SERIAL DESC NULLS LAST) AS TYPE_ID
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

But note that, This will give `ID 1 to the printer, 2 to laptop and 3 to the charger`. but it will be dynamic so no need to give static values in the query.

Cheers!!

Comment: Pay attention to tags. They tell you **which** tech is being asked about.